# What is the probability that the distance will reach ATLEAST 13?

Tags: probability, percentages

I have a list of distances (doesn't matter what the distance is of for this question), the list goes like this:

Distance of 1 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 2 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 4 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 5 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 7 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 8 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 13 occurs 7.5% of the time

Distance of 14 occurs 5.0% of the time

Distance of 15 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 16 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 18 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 20 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 21 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 22 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 23 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 25 occurs 5.0% of the time

Distance of 26 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 27 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 30 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 35 occurs 5.0% of the time

Distance of 37 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 38 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 40 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 49 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 50 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 55 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 61 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 62 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 64 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 74 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 78 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 86 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 88 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 89 occurs 2.5% of the time

Distance of 193 occurs 2.5% of the time

---

I want to know the probability in percentage of the "distance" reaching 13 OR above.

I'm guessing that it has an 85% chance, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the percentages sum to 100% (I didn't check but I assume they do), then the answer is the sum of all percentages from the line

> Distance of 13 occurs 7.5% of the time

on.

---

This is simply because if two events $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, then $P(A\text{ or }B) = P(A)+P(B)$.

Comment: So 7.5% + everything below it? Which is 85%

Comment: @LucMerenda Yup. Sum of everything but the first $6$ lines, which I think is 85%.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @LucMerenda Remember, if the answer is what you needed, then the standard thing to to is to *accept* it.

Comment: I know, but I have to wait 5 minutes.